# Jest & React & Typescript & React-Testing-Library error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a React/NextJS project setup using Typescript and am adding unit testing with Jest and React Testing Library.

A unit test for my component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import AppLayout from '.';

describe('<AppLayout>', () => {
  it('renders children', () => {
    const children = 'Test';
    const props = { pathname: '/' };
    const component = <AppLayout {...props}>{children}</AppLayout>;
    const { getByText } = render(component);
    expect(getByText(children)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This throws the following error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
```

Here's some key files in my project to help:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements",
        ["babel-plugin-styled-components", { "displayName": false }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.js**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    ".next",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['./'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```

My project compiles and runs fine but I'm guessing there's some configuration issue I need to fix to get my unit tests running correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This [`jest.config.js`](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/client/jest.config.js) works with Typescript, Jest, React Testing Library and without Babel.
To test it works, execute:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react.git
cd crisp-react/client
yarn && yarn test
```

Although `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` is not really needed due to being the default, you can look at the other settings.

As a sidenote, Babel is a [wonderful](https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/) software but you might consider setting `"target": "es5"` and using [react-app-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill) instead.

Comment: Not sure I quite follow your answer. My project uses NextJS (which uses babel) and typescript (also built into NextJS).

Comment: "if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files". Jest should use `ts-jest` to transform.

Comment: okay, but in my jest.config.js I have this line: `'^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',`. Isn't that telling Jest to use ts-jest to transform .ts or .tsx files?

Comment: Yes, it is telling that to Jest. I have noted it and that is why I brought up the issue with Babel. Which seems to be influencing Jest into stating that it will be Babel who Jest will use "to transform your files". Looks like an issue, hence the suggestion to replace Babel. I didn't know you use NextJS.

Comment: Okay. I don't think replacing Babel is an option with NextJS. It's built into the framework. I did mention I was using NextJS in my question.

Comment: That's right, you did mention. But I missed it. Replacing Babel is an [option](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ts-node) [using](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/search?q=next-with-typescript&unscoped_q=next-with-typescript) this [package](https://github.com/echoulen/next-with-typescript).

Comment: Thanks that looks useful. I'll take a look through those examples.